# Converting string date to a date and dropping the time in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a string date and time (ex: "6/30/2015 0:00") to just a date in this format: %Y/%m/%d. I am trying to do this for all values in a dataframe column. I almost have it but can't seem to get rid of the time part. I also need to apply this method to another column that might have null/blank values. This is what I have tried, any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  0:00

***Sample data (does not include all fields; which are 30+ long)
[image]

Here is a sample series of the first 5 values for `STATUS_DATE`:

```
0    6/30/2015 0:00
1    6/24/2015 0:00
2    6/24/2015 0:00
3    6/24/2015 0:00
4    6/24/2015 0:00
Name: STATUS_DATE, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a **[mcve]**. Speaking of, what do/don't you understand from that error?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(cnms_df['STATUS_DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'][:cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'].index(' ')[0]], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

Assuming your dates are consistent, it's just a matter of chopping off the time segment using `split`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmmm, with this I get a `TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable` error.

Comment: You're going to have to put up a sample of your data at this point, @gwydion93

Comment: Every single value in that column (there are no null or blanks for this column) area string type like this: `"6/30/2015 0:00"`

Comment: Again, add the output of `cnmf_df.sample(5)` to your question, please?

Comment: OK, I added what I could. There are 30+ columns so I only added up to `STATUS_DATE`. A sample series of those values is included.

Comment: The solution given in the comment by @Quang Hoang works with the sample you provided.

Answer (score 1):

if all your date times are `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M` then this will work

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['6/30/2015 0:00', '6/30/2015 15:35']})


print(df)

              date
0   6/30/2015 0:00
1  6/30/2015 15:35

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").dt.normalize()

print(df)

        date
0 2015-06-30
1 2015-06-30

print(df.dtypes)

date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This wokrs, but how do I drop the `00:00:00` timestamp? I just need the date.

Comment: the `.dt.normalize()` should drop it for you?

Comment: After running it, I checked it with `print(cnms_df['STATUS_DATE'][0])` which prints `2015-06-30 00:00:00`.

Comment: you could do `dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')` but you'll loose your datetime dtype @gwydion93

Comment: Also, how would I handle None or blank/null string dates?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(....,errors='coerce')` or `errors='ignore'` @gwydion93 coerce will convert to NaT and ignore will leave them as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can discard the time part before converting the string date to datetime64[ns].

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['6/30/2015 0:00']})
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split().str[0], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
print(df)


date    new_date
0   6/30/2015 0:00  2015-06-30

df.dtypes

date                object
new_date    datetime64[ns]
```

Note: I created the column new_date to compare with the string format date, ideally you would just assign the date to the same variable